# 2D affine conversion's coefficients

Tags: r, affine-transformation

I would like to calculate coefficients of a 2D affine conversion between two images.
Let me know of online pages that can help make programs using C or C++ or provide an application. I need a program or application which can calculate coefficients of an affine conversion using coordinates of corresponding points.

Comment: You can use my R package called [vec2dtransf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vec2dtransf/vec2dtransf.pdf). It can take your control points as input and give you the parameters calling the getParameters() function. See the 'Control Points' section here: http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/302-affine-and-similarity-transformations-in-r

Comment: How do you calculate the corresponding points?

Comment: @nickves: Not sure who/what you're asking, but i think the coords of corresponding points (in two different systems) are *given*.

Comment: Yes I wasn't clear enough. I am asking because I have the feeling that the OP question is related with the computer vision domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my R package called [vec2dtransf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vec2dtransf/vec2dtransf.pdf).

It can take your control points as input and give you the parameters calling the `getParameters()` function. See the `Control Points` section in this post:

http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/302-affine-and-similarity-transformations-in-r

Answer (score 0):

The free CoGo program, [Copan for Windows](http://www.underhill.ca/software/manuals/windows/user_manual/Transformations.html), can calculate the best-fit, rigid-body (1D rotation and a 2D shift) or similarity (1D rotation, a 1D scale, and a 2D shift) transformation between two sets of controls points.

(I programmed much of Copan.)